# Is it okay to read data from UI elements in another thread?

Tags: android, multithreading

I just found out that some of my code is (unindentionally) running in a worker thread and reads some data from UI elements:
e.g. `checkbox.isChecked()`, `textView.getText()`

and to my surprise, this works just fine...
I expected that it would crash with an exception (like the following exception that I get when I want to write to UI elements):

```
android.view.ViewRootImpl$CalledFromWrongThreadException: Only the original thread that created a view hierarchy can touch its views.
```

According to the [Android docs](https://developer.android.com/training/multiple-threads/communicate-ui.html):

> Only objects running on the UI thread have access to other objects on
>   that thread. Because tasks that you run on a thread from a thread pool
>   aren't running on your UI thread, they don't have access to UI
>   objects.

So, is it really okay to read data from UI elements from other threads?
If not: why is there no exception?

Comment: *touch its views* means *modify*

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> is it really okay to read data from UI elements from other threads?

No, but not for the reasons that you may be thinking.

First, as soon as you fork the background thread, the user might press BACK or otherwise do something that destroys your activity. It is not safe to try to use widgets of a destroyed activity.

Second, there is little to no thread synchronization logic in the `View` class or its subclasses. The main application thread may be modifying the data at the same time that you are trying to use it, resulting in possible concurrency issues.

I would pass the data from the widgets into the thread (e.g., thread constructor).

> why is there no exception?

AFAIK, that specific exception is only thrown on setters or other things that modify the contents of the widget. This does not mean that any code that does not raise that exception is guaranteed to be safe.

Answer (score 0):

You **can't** redraw (invalidate) your `View`s outside main thread which is also UI thread. Setting text for `TextView` also causes redrawing view ofc... But getting text just returns `String` (or `Editable`?), so its working...

Note that there are some other restrictions and limitations, e.g. when you pass `EditText` to some `AsyncTask`, but while it's working the main `Activity` (holding passed view) finish then you might get NPE, because view is also gone... In this and similar cases [WeakReferences](https://developer.android.com/reference/java/lang/ref/WeakReference.html) are very usefull